# Python way to write a looping function that can accept customizable functions

Tags: python, function, loops

I have a function I use frequently to loop over PDFs, turn each page into text, then does various things inside it, then outputs the results.

```
def loop_through_PDF(filename):
 
    with fitz.open(filename) as doc:
        try:
            text = ""
        
            for count, page in enumerate(doc, start = 1):

                text = page.getText()

                if text is not None:
                    # apply various functions to text

                    # create results document(s)

            try:
                doc.save(f'{filename}_new.pdf')
                st.info("PDF saved successfully")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    return
```

Very basic question.  What is the Pythonic way to construct this function so that it is easily reusable and I can easily "plug in" different actions (functions) within the loop?  Do I have it backwards? Should the "do things" functions somehow be calling the "by page" loops?

Comment: You can pass functions (by reference) as parameters to other functions

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just take the action (function) in params?

```py
def loop_through_PDF(filename, action):
    ...


def some_action(text):
    ...


loop_through_PDF(..., some_action)
```

Comment: Or even better `(filename, *actions)`